# C#: Using a string variable to call and give names to other stuff

Tags: c#

So I want to use a string variable to call or declare other stuff.
For example: I write down "some_random_name" in a text box and then press a button that calls a function which declares a variable or object called "some_random_name".
Another example: I have declared a variable from type integer called "a_variable". I write down this name in a text box and then I press a button that calls a function which shows me the value of "a_variable".
The second example can also be done this way:

```
if (the_wanted_variable == "a_variable") show_value(a_variable);
```

But that's a different question.

I have found a solution... but I couldn't understand it. It was about Reflections. Maybe a need an easier to understand explanation how to do it (no matter how big it is).

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at examples here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is a way to examine/use the properties/methods of an object at runtime.  Some explanations here:

[C#: Can someone explain the practicalities of reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723328/c-can-someone-explain-the-practicalities-of-reflection)

Comment: Looks like a really handy topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating different variables for each key/value pair entered by the user, you could store all key/value pairs in one [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Reflection is an option; but if the needs of your program are very predictable you can avoid it for a potentially easier solution.

In the example you've given - if the user is presented with a textbox and they enter the name of a variable like 'MyTest1' and can press a button called 'Add 1' you could accomplish it with a key/value pair dictionary.

In other words - if the user enters text that they haven't entered before, you create a new integer value and set it's value to 0.  If the user clicks on a button, it calls a predefined function on that value associated with that key.  'Add 1' to a newly created key would return '1'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to store the variables.

```
Dictionary<string,string> Variables;
```

if you don't want strings, you can use a `Dictionary<string, object>` but you have to be aware of the type to cast it when you click the button.